# What is meant by correlation between individual scores under a bi-factor and unidimensional model >0.90?

Tags: factor-analysis

I have been looking at the COSMIN criteria for evaluating the measurement properties of exploratory factor analyses. The criteria for a sufficient bi-factor model are described as “standardized loadings on a common factor >.30 AND correlation between individual scores under a bi-factor and unidimensional model >0.90.
Could anybody explain what correlation between individual scores under a bi-factor and unidimensional model >0.90 refers to?

Comment: You computed factor scores under both bifactor and unidimensional models and they were highly correlated? Person scores, regardless of the assumptions under which you compute them, tend to be highly correlated in most situations.